# I have a light switch that crosses multiple breakers

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker

The switch is part of a 3way gangbox.  I recently had the panel updated to a 220 from 100.  But the electricians didn't map it any better than it was already mapped and just essentially gave me more capacity but no more information for the tune of 5K.
My issue is that I'm trying to turn off a switch so that I can set it up for a smart switch but I can't identify which breaker it's on.  It appears to be on several.  Why would it be wired that way?  Why would someone wire a switch across multiple breakers?   Here's the test - kill all of the power everything goes out.... great I'm safe!  BUT flip the breakers one by one and this thing still lights up with the tester and the voltage is high enough for me to wonder why it and what it's connected to.

Thoughts?

Rob

Comment: How many breakers does this switch appear to be on, and what are you using to check for the presence of voltage?

Comment: i.e. if the multiple switches in the box are on multiple breakers (possibly annoying, yet allowed) and you're using a non-contact tester, you may be picking up a different live breaker than the one for the switch in question.

Comment: Sounds like the possibility of phantom voltage since you stated there was enough voltage to make you believe it was connected. I have seen phantom voltages within just a few volts of line voltage when the wires run parallel in close proximity for a run. The worst case ever was a man that wired his own house and he had no twists in the wire at all and used wire stacking cable holders full voltage in the bedrooms measured 1 of 4 circuits turned on. It was the neatest and cleanest I have ever seen. Drove him nuts I had him plug in a desk lamp and turn it on then that circuit was dead Or lamp on